# Problem with getting count with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display wordpress image using it ID but the code i use is giving an error which is

```
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/monstajamss/template-parts/content-article.php on line 10
```

This is my code

```
<div class="image large">
    <?php $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()); $alt = get_post_meta($thumb_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); if(count($alt)) ?>
    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('large-size'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>">
</div>
```

Comment: Pretty self-explanatory - `count` expects an array...you are not passing an array. `print_r()` your `$alt` variable. Also, why are you using `count()`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @disinfor I get the alt which is ```Dutchavelli Bando Diaries Remix```

Comment: Is that a string? Why are you using `count()` - what are you counting?

Comment: @disinfor how do i resolve this please, i want to add image alt??

Comment: You are using get_post_meta incorrectly, I'll post an answer with how to use it properly in what you're trying to do. @disinfor get_post_meta returns an array by default, the OP seems a bit confused about how to use the function properly :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten - The way OP used it, it wouldn't return the array, because OP passed the key AND set the single value param to TRUE. I was curious what `count()` was supposed to accomplish.

Comment: @disinfor To me, this has all the hallmarks of bits of code copied from various places and pieced without any understanding what they mean. They probably saw someone pass `true` into get_post_meta once and someone else use `count` to check the array they got returned before processing the results that got.

Comment: I would agree with that assessment!

Comment: Actually when i removed the count i noticed it worked.

Comment: Yes, it will work because of the reasons I explained in my answer - my answer was about more than just showing you the correct code :) -  but you will also get a blank alt attribute so I also added a condition to check if it's empty in case you wanted to set a default alt value

Comment: Yeah, it will work when you remove `count`, because you were adding a conditional that `count` would evaluate to true - which it never would, because you were not passing an array to `count`. Also, `count` literally counts the array elements, so was the wrong approach if you wanted a conditional check before adding the `alt` information. Fluffy's answer basically adds a conditional that checks if the variable is set first.

Comment: @FluffyKitten and Disinfor Thanks Guys :)

Comment: you got it! good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just using `get_post_meta` incorrectly - it returns an array by default, but you are passing in `true` as the third parameter which changes it to return **a single value only** - see the [Code Reference for get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/).

Therefore your return value is not array, so you don't need to try count (which only works with arrays) or anything to evaluate an array of values before using it - it already has a single value so you just need to do the following:

```
<div class="image large">
    <?php $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()); 
          $alt = get_post_meta($thumb_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); 
     ?>
     <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('large-size'); ?>" 
         <?php 
          // only include the alt attrib if the alt text is not empty
          // (or you could set a default value, or whatever else you might want to do)
          if ($alt): ?>
             alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>" 
         <?php endif; ?>
     />
</div>
```